# Need to know more about this art

Tags: art

This was a birthday gift I received a couple of weeks ago.  I'm trying to figure out where it came from, what the images mean, and about how old it is.  It's at least a hundred years old. [image: wall art scroll]

Comment: Consider asking here: https://dharmawheel.net/

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely a Tibetan [Thanka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thangka) which depicts 3 "levels". Based on the depictions, it's probably [Vajrayana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vajrayana), specifically [Gelug-pa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelug), lit. "yellow hats" - this is the Tibetan Buddhist branch to which the Dalai Lama belongs.

The top level depicts the Buddha surrounded by females, most likely [Dakini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dakini).

The central level depicts 3 people with a very recognizable [yellow hat](https://www.thoughtco.com/thmb/3SAbRmxF9Xpd-VHDs4wA13zZ18M=/300x474/filters:no_upscale()/dalailamayellowhat-56a0c4523df78cafdaa4d658.jpg), so probably they are  [Tulku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulku), possibly the [Dalai Lama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalai_Lamas) in the center, the [Panchen Lama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panchen_Lama) and the [Samding Dorje Pagmo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samding_Dorje_Phagmo) or [Karmapa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karmapa). They are depicted as slightly above the world since they are considered reincarnations of [Bodhisattva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodhisattva)

The building in the bottom section could be a depiction of the [Potala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potala_Palace).

The two figures depicted in the bottom section are most likely high monks, but I can't think of any specific persons or roles for these.

The many occurences of Green, Red, Blue, Yellow and White refer to [Pancha-Varna](https://www.tibettravel.org/tibetan-buddhism/meanings-of-colors-in-tibet.html)

As for the age of the painting, it's very difficult to tell, as iconography in Tibetan Buddhist art has changed very little in the last few hundred years.

You might enjoy this video on [decoding symbolism in Thanka](https://asiasociety.org/new-york/guide-decoding-buddhist-symbolism-tibetan-art)

Comment: May be the bottom figures depict offering of bare necessities of a monk (Civara = robes, Pindapata = alms-food, Senasana = monasteries, Gilanapratya = medications) to Dalai Lama. I cannot see the top level Buddha as Dakini. I suppose that depicts Amitābha Buddha because of Samadhi mudra, and the appearance of begging bowl. But the color of the Buddha doesn't support that interpretation.